# pgadmin III doesn't work due to "The server lacks instrumentation functions."

Tags: postgresql

When pgAdmin III is used to open a PostgreSQL database the following message appears.
There does not seem to be any obvious package listed in the Ubuntu Software Center for this.

> The server lacks instrumentation functions.
>
> pgadmin III uses some support functions that are not available by default in all PostgreSQL versions.  These enable some tasks that make life easier when dealing with log files and configuration files.
>
> The adminpack is installed and activated by default if you are running the one-click installer of PostgreSQL.  On Unix, you may have to install the contrib package, either with your package installer tool or by compilation.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the package which needs to be installed is called `postgresql-contrib`. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Comment: Depending on the version, you may need to run something like:

    `sudo su postgres -c psql < /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/adminpack.sql`

then restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

Once you install postgresql-contrib using below command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Adminpack is located in the below path

```
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql
```

To load the adminpack use the below command

```
sudo su postgres -c psql < /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql
```

Then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing I couldn't load the extension, got the message:

```
Use "CREATE EXTENSION adminpack" to load this file.
```

I have to use the following command to make work:

```
$ sudo -u postgres -i
$ psql [dbname]
# CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still get this issue after installing pgAdminIII from Ubuntu software center, then simply installing pgAdmin4 from the official website will solve your problem. Don't use pgAdminIII, it is outdated.

You can see that pgAdminIII is not available for download from the [official website](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/) anymore. This is also where you could download pgAdmin 4.